# ActiveRecord find all parents that have associated children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I don't know why I can't figure this out, I think it should be fairly simple.  I have two models (see below).  I'm trying to come up with a named scope for SupplierCategory that would find all SupplierCategory(s) (including :suppliers) who's associated Supplier(s) are not empty.

I tried a straight up join, `named_scope :with_suppliers, :joins => :suppliers` which gives me only categories with suppliers, but it gives me each category listed separately, so if a category has 2 suppliers, i get the category twice in the returned array:

Currently I'm using:

```
named_scope :with_suppliers, :include => :suppliers
```

and then in my view I'm using:

```
<%= render :partial => 'category', :collection => @categories.find_all{|c| !c.suppliers.empty? } %>
```

Not exactly eloquent but illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

**Class Definitions**

```
class SupplierCategory < AR
  has_many :suppliers, :order => "name"
end

class Supplier < AR
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

Comment: In `Subbplier` class you meant `belongs_to :supplier_category` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one more approach:

```
named_scope :with_suppliers, :include    => :suppliers, 
                             :conditions => "suppliers.id IS NOT NULL"
```

This works because Rails uses `OUTER` JOIN for `include` clause. When no matching rows are found the query returns NULL values for supplier columns. Hence `NOT NULL` check returns the matching rows.

**Rails 4**

```
scope :with_suppliers, { includes(:steps).where("steps.id IS NOT NULL") }
```

Or using a static method:

```
def self.with_suppliers
  includes(:steps).where("steps.id IS NOT NULL")
end
```

**Note:**

This solution eager loads suppliers.

```
categories = SupplierCategory.with_suppliers
categories.first.suppliers #loaded from memory
```

Comment: Definitely the most succinct of all the solutions and works perfectly!! Thanks

Comment: Updated for rails 4:

`scope :in_use, -> {includes(:steps).where("steps.id IS NOT NULL")}`

and its counterpart
`scope :not_in_use, -> {includes(:steps).where("steps.id IS  NULL")}`

Answer (score 3):

```
class SupplierCategory < AR
  has_many :supliers

  def self.with_supliers
    self.all.reject{ |c| c.supliers.empty? }
  end
end

SupplierCategory.with_supliers
#=> Array of SuplierCategories with supliers
```

Another way more flexible using named_scope

```
class SupplierCategory < AR
  has_many :supliers
  named_scope :with_supliers, :joins => :supliers, :select => 'distinct(suplier_categories.id), suplier_categories.*', :having => "count(supliers.id) > 0"
end

SupplierCategory.with_supliers(:all, :limit => 4)
#=> first 4 SupplierCategories with suppliers
```

Comment: I believe using the `join` is faster, isn't it? I don't know if it's relevant in his case... but I'm curious =P

Answer (score 3):

Simpler version:

```
named_scope :with_suppliers, :joins => :suppliers, :group => :id
```

If you want to use it frequently, consider using [counter_cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be something like

```
#model SupplierCategory
named_scope :with_suppliers, 
   :joins => :suppliers,
   :select => "distinct(supplier_categories), supplier_categories.*",
   :conditions => "suppliers.supplier_categories_id = supplier_categories.id"
```

Let me know if it works for you.

**Edit:**
Using fl00r's idea:

```
named_scope :with_suppliers, 
   :joins => :suppliers,
   :select => "distinct(supplier_categories), supplier_categories.*",
   :having => "count(supliers.id) > 0"
```

I believe this is the faster way.

Comment: Are you sure you should use singular forms of model supplier_category instead of supplier_categories?