# Rails: How to get objects with at least one child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

After googling, browsing SO and [reading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), there doesn't seem to be a Rails-style way to efficiently get only those **`Parent` objects which have *at least one* `Child` object** (through a `has_many :children` relation). In plain SQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM parents
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
                 FROM children
                WHERE parent_id = parents.id)
```

The closest I've come is

```
Parent.all.reject { |parent| parent.children.empty? }
```

(based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737560/96588)), but it's really inefficient because it runs a separate query for each `Parent`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
Parent.joins(:children).uniq.all
```

Comment: This results in a single SQL statement, and it's short and readable. Awesome.

Comment: Yes you did. **Parent.joins(:children).uniq.all** is an array and **Parent.joins(:children).uniq** is an ActiveRelation object. Note ActiveRelation objects are lazy and don't execute until explicity requested to. Calling **all** forces the object to evaluate the SQL with the DB

Comment: Why does this work? I understand SQL but...can someone please explain?

Comment: Wizardry! How can this be done for multiple has_many associations

Comment: pure SQL version: Parent.joins(:children).distinct.all

Answer (score 14):

As of [Rails 5.1](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations), `uniq` is deprecated and `distinct` should be used instead.

```
Parent.joins(:children).distinct
```

This is a follow-up on [Chris Bailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9923196/1417223). `.all` is removed as well from the original answer as it doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer (`Parent.joins(:children).uniq`) generates SQL using DISTINCT but it can be slow query. For better performance, you should write SQL using EXISTS:

```
Parent.where<<-SQL
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM children c WHERE c.parent_id = parents.id)
SQL
```

EXISTS is much faster than DISTINCT. For example, here is a post model which has comments and likes:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In database there are 100 posts and each post has 50 comments and 50 likes. Only one post has no comments and likes:

```
# Create posts with comments and likes
100.times do |i|
  post = Post.create!(title: "Post #{i}")
  50.times do |j|
    post.comments.create!(content: "Comment #{j} for #{post.title}")
    post.likes.create!(user_name: "User #{j} for #{post.title}")
  end
end

# Create a post without comment and like
Post.create!(title: 'Hidden post')
```

If you want to get posts which have at least one comment and like, you might write like this:

```
# NOTE: uniq method will be removed in Rails 5.1
Post.joins(:comments, :likes).distinct
```

The query above generates SQL like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "posts".* 
FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
INNER JOIN "likes" ON "likes"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
```

But this SQL generates 250000 rows(100 posts * 50 comments * 50 likes) and then filters out duplicated rows, so it could be slow.

In this case you should write like this:

```
Post.where <<-SQL
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments c WHERE c.post_id = posts.id)
AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM likes l WHERE l.post_id = posts.id)
SQL
```

This query generates SQL like this:

```
SELECT "posts".* 
FROM "posts" 
WHERE (
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments c WHERE c.post_id = posts.id) 
AND 
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM likes l WHERE l.post_id = posts.id)
)
```

This query does not generate useless duplicated rows, so it could be faster.

Here is benchmark:

```
              user     system      total        real
Uniq:     0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.074396)
Exists:   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003711)
```

It shows EXISTS is 20.047661 times faster than DISTINCT.

I pushed the sample application in GitHub, so you can confirm the difference by yourself:

https://github.com/JunichiIto/exists-query-sandbox

Comment: Excellent research!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31755299 has more "rails-like" syntax for generating EXISTS queries

Answer (score 3):

I have just modified this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565879/rails-3-finding-parents-which-have-no-child) for your need.

```
Parent.joins("left join childrens on childrends.parent_id = parents.id").where("childrents.parent_id is not null")
```

Comment: This produces *duplicates* (see [@ChrisBailey's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9923196/96588))

Comment: Replicating an inner join using an outer join is inefficient and bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

You just want an inner join with a distinct qualifier

```
SELECT DISTINCT(*) 
FROM parents
JOIN children
ON children.parent_id = parents.id
```

This can be done in standard active record as

```
Parent.joins(:children).uniq
```

However if you want the more complex result of find all parents with no children
you need an outer join

```
Parent.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN children on children.parent_id = parent.id").
where(:children => { :id => nil })
```

which is a solution which sux for many reasons. I recommend Ernie Millers [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) library which will allow you to do

```
Parent.joins{children.outer}.where{children.id == nil}
```

Comment: look at @chris-bailey's answer when you need to use a `JOIN` for some reason while writing it in a clean and concise way.

Comment: This is equivalent to @ChrisBailey's answer - No go.

Comment: It is the same solution I proposed. However it is very rare to only need to do a join. Squeel shines for complex queries that AR get's very ugly with.

Answer (score 1):

try including the children with [`#includes()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

```
Parent.includes(:children).all.reject { |parent| parent.children.empty? }
```

This will make 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM parents;
SELECT * FROM children WHERE parent_id IN (5, 6, 8, ...);
```

**[UPDATE]**

The above solution is usefull when you need to have the Child objects loaded.
But `children.empty?` can also use a *counter cache*<sup>[1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column),[2](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to#562-Caveat-and-design-hints-regarding-counter-cache)</sup> to determine the amount of children.

For this to work you need to add a new column to the `parents` table:

```
# a new migration
def up
  change_table :parents do |t|
    t.integer :children_count, :default => 0
  end

  Parent.reset_column_information
  Parent.all.each do |p|
    Parent.update_counters p.id, :children_count => p.children.length
  end
end

def down
  change_table :parents do |t|
    t.remove :children_count
  end
end
```

Now change your `Child` model:

```
class Child
  belongs_to :parent, :counter_cache => true
end
```

At this point you can use `size` and `empty?` without touching the `children` table:

```
Parent.all.reject { |parent| parent.children.empty? }
```

Note that `length` doesn't use the counter cache whereas `size` and `empty?` do.

Comment: This is a bad answer as the correct answer is an inner join. The above is very inefficient and make multiple queries and ruby loops.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing No my first solution will never make multiple queries while looping through the parents. (note the `.includes(:children)`) It is true though that Rails might turn the 2 queries above into 1 query (with a JOIN) when it needs too.

Comment: Never said it would make multiple queries whilst looping. Your solution does makes "multiple queries", two of them and then you loop through the returned set in ruby using reject. That is very slow compared to a fast inner join in the DB.

Comment: However to be fair in general the solution you propose does fix the general **1+N** problem that the OP sees in his original solution. It's just not the right solution for this specific problem :)