# Filter for parent objects with at least one child within a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to return Users with Books which are part of a scope -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :published, -> { where (status: 'Published') }
end
```

So

```
Book.published
```

returns all the published books. I'm trying to define a scope of all users who have one or more published books.

Knowing that

```
User.joins(:books).uniq.all
```

returns all users with a book (from [Rails: How to get objects with at least one child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922833/rails-how-to-get-objects-with-at-least-one-child)) - can I add a scope to that, or is there a better approach?

Comment: So you want all parents with a child who are within the scope `attends_club`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the ***class name*** for the ***model*** should be ***singular*** and If I understood correctly, you want all users with a book within the scope `published` then I would place that `scope` in `User` model with a slight change like below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  scope :published, -> { joins(:books).where(books: { status: 'Published' }) }
end
```

Now you can do `User.published` which returns all users with a book whose status is ***Published***

Comment: I'm just working through it now - I currently get the error message - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "child" - googling this got the following rails issue on github - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13531#issuecomment-35103068 - 'm trying to work out if its the same thing - what do you think?

Comment: @RADan Is your table named `child`? or `children`?

Comment: can i just check - that -> { joins(children) ... is that the plural or singular of the class name?

Comment: I was trying to make the class names generic, but I don;t think i made a good choice :)

Comment: @RADan Try putting `self.table_name = "child"` in `Child` model and see.

Comment: I think rather than tying to make it generic I should just use actual table names, as is less confusing - will update question :)

Comment: @RADan Yeah! table names should be plural. In your case **child** should be **children**