# Display categories that have posts in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to display a list of categories that have posts. Sounds simple but i'm a little stuck. 
Similar to this

[ActiveRecord find all parents that have associated children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737073/activerecord-find-all-parents-that-have-associated-children?rq=1)

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Can you please help. I tried named scope but breaks the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a scope like this

```
scope :with_posts, -> { includes(:posts).where("posts.id IS NOT NULL") }
```

or using counter_cache

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  scope :with_posts, -> { where("posts_count > ?", 0) }
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, counter_cache: true
end
```

Note that you have to add a `posts_count` integer field to the `categories` table for this to work. It is also advisable to save all your categories the first time to populate this field.

Comment: Works when i use it on the controller  def show
    @categories = Category.where('posts_count > ?', 0)
  end